# Include Graphic that spans whole site minus Heading

Tags: graphics, scaling

I have the following Problem: I have a big image I want to insert into my document with an angle of 270°. However I don't get the image to span the whole page. This is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
   \centering
   \vspace{-1cm}
   \includegraphics[angle=270, totalheight=\textheight - 6cm, keepaspectratio]{Datenmodell/Updates.png}
   \caption{Updates in der Datenbank}
   \label{fig:database-update0}
\end{figure}
```

If I remove the `\vspace{-1cm}` the image will be rendered on the next page, although there is space on the page left. (The image is as big as the box that is shown, so no additional padding within the image)

Here is what it looks like:

[image]
[image]

So as you can see there clearly is space left (even more than 1cm).

Comment: you probably need `[!h]` to give more of the page to floats, and just increase `totalheight=\textheight - 6cm` to whataver size fits

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That was it thank you very much!